# Rotate objects around Cylinder With Geo Nodes?

Tags: modifiers, geometry-nodes

[image]

I need to rotate these objects around the cylinder and have them stick straight out. but I'm using a Wave Modifier So I can't Apply rotation the way it needs. I also need to angle the objects downward randomly after.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure about the Wave modifier part, but to make them stick straight out, you need to align their rotations along the normals of the cylinder's faces using a *Capture Attribute* node. I also used a "not-equal to a vector in the Z direction" to stop it from distributing points on the caps of the cylinder.

Once they are aligned to the surface normals sticking out straight, you can now align them downwards, along a `X:0,Y:0,Z:-1` vector. Insert a *Random Value* multiplier in between, and it'll vary their rotation.

[image]

Comment: I copied your node setup and unfortunately I'm having the same issues. did you change the rotation of your instanced cylinder?

Comment: I didn't. You can see the axes of my instanced cylinder ("Thorn") in the middle window of my screenshot. You might want different Align Euler to Vector axis modes of yours is oriented different. If not, you can share your file so we could take a look.